# jquery selectors, how does "a+b+c+d" get interpretted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What does "a+b+c+d" mean? Is it the same as  "a + b + c + d"? I know what "+" does but is it read left to right or right to left? If "+" was instead made into ":adjacent(selector)" would it look like "a:adjacent(b):adjacent(c)..." or maybe "a:adjacent(b:adjacent(c...))"? Stacking them gets confusing as they seem different from the :xyz() style extension types.

Comment: Yes, `a+b+c+d` is the same as `a + b + c + d` in CSS or Sizzle/jQuery selectors if that's what you're asking. Did you try to do any testing or research, why do you have this problem? What makes you think they are different, for example? I'm not sure what you're asking with all the `:adjacent` stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a+b+c+d` means a `d` element that is immediately preceded by a `c` element that is immediately preceded by a `b` element that is immediately preceded by an `a` element. The spaces do not matter here. I have no idea what `:adjacent` would translate as, since that does not, to my knowledge, exist.

The `d` element here would be matched:

```
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c>Random stuff in here</c>
<d>Hello</d>
```

But not here:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d>Nope.</d>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works the [exact same way](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/j33FW/) as it would with two elements a + b. Stacking elements just mean the selector is more specific.